# Pagination as cross-cutting concern in cqrs with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, pagination, simple-injector

In my application design I'm trying to implement [Pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) as a [Cross-Cutting Concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) with the [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern applied to [an implementation](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) of the [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) pattern.

I also have a [multi-layered architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) and I have the opinion that pagination is **not** part of business logic (and thus a cross-cutting concern). This is a decision already made and should not be discussed in this topic.

In my design, the intention is that the presentation layer can consume a paginated query with a specific closed-generic type

```
IQueryHandler<GetAllItemsQuery, PaginatedQuery<Item>>
```

with the following signatures:

```
public class GetAllItemsQuery : PaginatedQuery<Item>

public class PaginatedQuery<TModel> :
    IQuery<PaginatedResult<TModel>>, IQuery<IEnumerable<TModel>>

public class PaginatedResult<TModel>
```

The idea is that the consumer should receive a `PaginatedResult` for a specific model, that contains the paginated items and some metadata (e.g. the total number of items of the query performed without pagination applied), so that the UI can render it's pagination.
The main philosophy of my design is that the queryhandler should just apply it's *business logic* (e.g. getting all items). It only describes how it would do this, it doesn't necessarily has to execute the query.
In my case a decorator on the queryhandler actually applies pagination on the query and executes it (e.g. by calling [`.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) on a [Linq to Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities) query).
What I want is that my queryhandler should be implemented like this:

```
public class GetAllItemsQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetAllItemsQuery, IEnumerable<Item>>
```

So that the return type of the handler is `IEnumerable<Item>`. This way the handler is forced to be [Single Responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
The problem I'm facing is probably the way I'm using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html). Because I'm registering my `IQueryHandler<,>` like

```
container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), assemblies);
```

which wouldn't verify my design, because of an obvious invalid configuration: I'm injecting `IQueryHandler<GetAllItemsQuery, PaginatedResult<Item>>` into my consumer, but don't actually implement it. Instead the handler implements `IQueryHandler<GetAllItemsQuery, IEnumerable<Item>>`.

So as a solution I tried to implement an [Interceptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern) and register that conditionally (note the usage of [C# 7.0 local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)):

```
Type PaginationInterceptorFactory(TypeFactoryContext typeContext)
{
    // IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TResult is PaginatedResult<TModel>
    var queryType = typeContext.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // TQuery
    var modelType = typeContext.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[1].GetGenericArguments()[0]; // TModel in PaginatedResult<TModel> as TResult
    return typeof(PaginatedQueryHandlerInterceptor<,>).MakeGenericType(queryType, modelType);
}
bool PaginationInterceptorPredicate(PredicateContext predicateContext) =>
    predicateContext.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsPaginatedQuery(); // if TQuery is of type PaginatedQuery<>

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), PaginationInterceptorFactory, Lifestyle.Singleton, PaginationInterceptorPredicate);
```

but this gives me an exception on verify:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type [TYPE] failed. This operation is only valid on generic types.
  Source=SimpleInjector
  StackTrace:
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()

Inner Exception 1:
ActivationException: This operation is only valid on generic types.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: This operation is only valid on generic types.
```

The exception is not really clear on what the *operation* is and why it's invalid. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Here is the implementation of the Interceptor:

```
public class PaginatedQueryHandlerInterceptor<TQuery, TModel> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, PaginatedResult<TModel>>
    where TQuery : PaginatedQuery<TModel>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, IEnumerable<TModel>> _queryHandler;

    public PaginatedQueryHandlerInterceptor(IQueryHandler<TQuery, IEnumerable<TModel>> queryHandler)
    {
        _queryHandler = queryHandler;
    }

    public PaginatedResult<TModel> Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        return (dynamic) _queryHandler.Handle(query);
    }
}
```

and the decorator:

```
public class PaginationQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
        where TQuery : class, IQuery<TResult>
    {
        private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> _decoratee;

        public PaginationQueryHandlerDecorator(
            IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> decoratee)
        {
            _decoratee = decoratee;
        }

        public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
        {
            query.ThrowIfNull(nameof(query));

            var result = _decoratee.Handle(query);

            if (query.IsPaginationQuery(out var paginatedQuery))
            {
                return Paginate(result, paginatedQuery.Pagination);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static TResult Paginate(TResult result, Pagination pagination)
        {
            return Paginate(result as dynamic, pagination.Page, pagination.ItemsPerPage);
        }

        private static PaginatedResult<TModel> Paginate<TModel>(IEnumerable<TModel> result, int page, int itemsPerPage)
        {
            var items = result as TModel[] ?? result.ToArray();

            var paginated = items.Skip(page * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage).ToArray();

            return new PaginatedResult<TModel>
            {
                Items = paginated,
                Count = items.Length
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a decision already made and should not be discussed in this topic.

Well.... if you insist :)

But at least prevent those queries from returning `IEnumerable<T>`, but return `IQueryable<T>` instead. The use of `IEnumerable<T>` will cause *all* data to be returned from the database, even if you page over it.

That said, I'm not sure what is wrong with your code, but I want to suggest a slightly different approach:

```
public class PagedQueryHandler<TQuery, TItem>
    : IQueryHandler<PagedQuery<TQuery, TItem>, Paged<TItem>>
    where TQuery : IQuery<IQueryable<TItem>>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, IQueryable<TItem>> handler;

    public PagedQueryHandler(IQueryHandler<TQuery, IQueryable<TItem>> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public Paged<TItem> Handle(PagedQuery<TQuery, TItem> query)
    {
        var paging = query.PageInfo ?? new PageInfo();
        IQueryable<TItem> items = this.handler.Handle(query.Query);
        return new Paged<TItem>
        {
            Items = items.Skip(paging.PageIndex * paging.PageSize)
                .Take(paging.PageSize).ToArray(),
            Paging = paging,
        };
    }
}
```

This generic `IQueryHandler` implementation can map a paged-query to a non-paged query. Here `Paged<T>` and `PageInfo` and `PagedQuery<TQuery, TItem>` are defined as follows:

```
public class Paged<T>
{
    public PageInfo Paging { get; set; }
    public T[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class PageInfo
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 20;
}

public class PagedQuery<TQuery, TItem> : IQuery<Paged<TItem>>
    where TQuery : IQuery<IQueryable<TItem>>
{
    public TQuery Query { get; set; }
    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
}
```

`PageInfo` and `Paged<T>` originate from this Github repo: https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices/tree/master/src/Contract/

`PagedQueryHandler<TQuery, TItem>` can be registered as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), typeof(PagedQueryHandler<,>));
```

With this class and its registration, you can simply inject a pageable query handler into a consumer, for instance:

```
public class ItemsController
{
    IQueryHandler<PagedQuery<GetAllItemsQuery, Item>, Paged<Item>> handler;

    public ItemsController(
        IQueryHandler<PagedQuery<GetAllItemsQuery, Item>, Paged<Item>> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(PagedQuery<GetAllItemsQuery, Item> query)
    {
        return View(this.handler.Handle(query));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is just a slight problem with your solution. That is that my `DbContext` is disposed when the `PagedQueryHandler` calls `.ToArray()`. Because I'm decorating my queryhandler with a `LifetimeScopeQueryHandlerProxy`.

Comment: This means that you should not decorate query handlers that return `IQueryable<T>` instances. Or ensure that the LifetimeScopeQueryHandlerProxy detects whether it is nested and prevent it from starting and disposing a DbContext. But that's not really a problem with my design, since your original post contains the same problem.

Comment: I've refactored my initial design to your *slightly different approach*, which now works perfectly. The reason I used `IEnumerable` in the original design was because my queries would inherit from `PaginatedQuery`, forcing the handler to return an `IEnumerable`, but letting the business decide whether it's an `IQueryable` under the hood or not (perhaps the underlying data model is something super performant). In your design, the query remains natural and the generic type constraint forces the handler to return an `IQueryable`. Downside is that the handler is forced to only return a query.

Comment: TBH I would personally stick with letting query handlers return page results directly and leave out the intermediate mapping that applies the paging. As you can see [here](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices/blob/master/src/BusinessLayer/QueryHandlers/GetUnshippedOrdersForCurrentCustomerQueryHandler.cs), the noise it adds is minimal, and IMO justifiable.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was indeed something I did wrong, but had nothing to do with Simple Injector.

When using the `RegisterConditional`, in the predicate this extension method was being called:

```
bool PaginationInterceptorPredicate(PredicateContext predicateContext) =>
    predicateContext.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsPaginatedQuery();
```

The implementation of `IsPaginatedQuery` was wrong and caused the exception:

```
public static bool IsPaginatedQuery(this Type queryType) => 
    queryType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(PaginatedQuery<>));
```

Because the query also implements a *non-generic* interface `IPagination`, thus the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method caused the exception.